# How to get a unique key from firebase auth to use as a password alternative for data encryption

Tags: flutter, encryption, firebase-authentication

I created a password manager in flutter, which stores password encrypted passwords in an db. I access this db via the backend, which is written in python. As a user in the app, you are able to set a master password, which after each login is passed to the backend, to encrypt the data. I now want to add sign in with google functionality (firebase authentication), so that you don't need to type in your master password every time. Is it possible to receive something like a key or a token from firebase after each successful google-login which you can use instead of the master password?

I noticed already that there is this uid in the firebase user class (which i receive from `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredencial(google_sign_in_credencial)` in the google registration progress) which is unique for every user, but i dont think that this is secure enough to replace this sensitive master password. I also heard from JWT Authorization, but i am not sure, if it's the right thing for that.